# Square surface with four fixed points

Tags: geometry, 3d, surfaces

I'm looking for a function of two variables, $f(x, y)$, that satisfies the following constraints:

$f(0, 0) = z_1$

$f(0, 1) = z_2$

$f(1, 0) = z_3$

$f(1, 1) = z_4$

and within the unit square, it should be "as smooth as possible". I'm not sure what to google for, but I think that I'm trying to model something like a "soap film" spanning the unit square. I found this on google images:

http://aoeu.se/so/soapfilm.gif

I suspect that I could let $f$ be the average of $z_1, ..., z_4$ weighted on the distances to the corners, but A) I'm not sure this is the best solution, and B) I was hoping for a simpler formula.

Answer (score 2):

I know two approaches :

1. [Bilinear filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_filtering)
2. [Minimal surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_surface)

The first is very simple but not that nice looking. The second is much more beautiful but not hat easy to implement.

The picture looks like to be about a minimal surface.